# Combine XML layout with Java Layout

Tags: java, android, xml

i have created a very simple java game using only java classes in android studio.

i want to add a score board to that game to the top right corner.

the only thing i can come up with is to add a textview to the right corner and then have it changed everytime the players score increases.

the problem is that i dont know how to get that textview in the java class.

because the game right now is only using java code and no xml layouts.
so how can i get a textview element in the java code and place it in top right corner.

Comment: why downvote and no feedback

Comment: maybe a Jlabel, is there any other option?

Comment: you you know the parent layout of your view? created in code

Comment: i dont have any layout. i just have java code and background using photoshop pics

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("Text Here");
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT); // align top right
frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

there is no need to combine xml layout with Java class code